# Is a bottle of Sake that was open for roughly two years safe to drink?

Tags: sake

I have an already opened bottle of sake in my possession that I'd like to drink. I opened it roughly two years ago, it was sealed with a simple screw-cap and stored at room temperature. Due to its relatively low alcohol content (15%) I wonder if it's still safe to drink.

If it isn't, is it safe for cooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's safe to drink. I don't think you want to drink it or cook with it. The rule of thumb if it tastes bad, why would you cook with it? The chances that it actually tastes good at this point are about zero. You could do a taste test if you really want, but it won't hurt you (unless you drink too much and then you'll get a hangover)

Comment: I think you should re-read that question. ;)

Comment: Ha! I read two weeks! It's toast...